# How to use index signature for nested object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How to specify index signature for nested object? I have component where i need to define type for it.

```
const data = {
  name:'Jack',
  age:10,
  address: {
    city:'Boston',
    country:'USA'
  }
}

const DataCell = (data:{[key: string]: string })=> {
  return <span>{data.address.country}</span>
}
```

if i specify it like this I get `Property 'country' does not exist on type 'String'.`
I do not want to hard code the interface.

Comment: If you don't want to hard-code the interface, just use `data: any` as your parameter. Then again, might as well just switch to plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what your object looks like, you can simply use it as the type.

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number
  address: {
    city: string
    country: string
  }
}

const DataCell = (data: User)=> {
  return <span>{data.address.country}</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do but your declaration will result in the value `data.address` is `string`

you can style it like this instead:

```
interface Data {
  name: string
  age: number
  address: {
    city: string
    country: string
  }
}

const DataCell = (data: Data)=> {
  return <span>{data.address.country}</span>
}
```